# How to use a newer version of parquet jar on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr

The latest EMR 4.1.0 bundles with Hive 1.0.0 and Spark 1.5.0, and Hive 1.0.0 uses `parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.5.0.jar` while Spark uses `parquet-hadoop-1.7.0.jar`

Unfortunately the version parquet 1.5.0 can not read files generated by parquet 1.7.0.

I tried to use `add jar parquet-hive-bundle-1.7.0.jar` in Hive shell but no luck, Hive still used its bundled old Parquet jar.

Then I tried to replace the old jar with the newer jar, however I couldn't find any parquet related jars even using the command `sudo find / "*parquet*.jar"`.

However I copied `parquet-hive-bundle-1.7.0.jar` to `/usr/lib/hive/lib` but it didn't work, Hive still used the old parquet jar and couldn't read my parquet files. Normally this way works in Cloudera distribution.

So my question is, where is the parquet jar and how can I replace it with a newer version?

Comment: Facing the same issue with Spark generated parquets that cannot be read by Hive 1.0.0. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Two solutions: 1. wait for the EMR team to upgrade  Hive to 1.0.1; 2. Set up another Hive cluster using Cloudera CDH, in this solution I use an EMR cluster to run Spark jobs and use the Cloudera Hive cluster to run SQL queries

Comment: Thanks for the response. How about the thriftserver that ships with Spark? It is based on a newer version of hive. Did you try that?

Comment: That's a third solution, I haven't tried it yet, you can give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by adding the new parquet jar location to the environment variable 'HADOOP_CLASSPATH' in environment or .profile or .bashrc file

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/var/lib/hive/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.9.0.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Run below command to get the hive command location

```
which hive
```

Open 'hive' file under /usr/bin/(Your hive location)

```
vi /usr/bin/hive
```

You should see something like below.

Take a backup of the hive file and add an echo command for the HADOOP_CLASSPATH at the end before exec as below.

**hive**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/atlas/hook/hive" ]; then
 if [ -z "${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}" ]; then
  export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/atlas/hook/hive/*
 else
  export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/atlas/hook/hive/*
 fi
fi

...

if [ -z "${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}" ]; then
 export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HCATALOG_JAR_PATH}
else
 export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:${HCATALOG_JAR_PATH}
fi
```

**echo "Classpath=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH"**

```
exec "${HIVE_HOME}/bin/hive.distro" "$@"
```

Run hive command to display the classpath.

Once we get the actual classpath, we know where to add the new jar file to take priority over the old parquet jar.

In this case, if we set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH, the classpath of hive will be prefixed with the value in HADOOP_CLASSPATH.

So adding the HADOOP_CLASSPATH value with new parquet jar fixed the issue.

I don't know whether this is a right fix but its working.